# Summarizing a CSV data into data frame by averaging based on two headers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV [data](http://dpaste.com/3J2TRSV.txt):

```
id,gene,celltype,stem,stem,stem,bcell,bcell,tcell
id,gene,organs,bm,bm,fl,pt,pt,bm
134,foo,about_foo,20,10,11,23,22,79
222,bar,about_bar,17,13,55,12,13,88
```

Notice that it contains two headers. What I want to do is to group
the 2nd row onwards and average them by organ and cell type.
So that it creates hierarchical data frame like this:

```
bm       stem,         bcell,  tcell
    foo  (20+10)/2     0        79/1=79
    bar  (17+13)/2     0        88/1=88



fl        stem,        bcell,    tcell
    foo    11/1=11       0         0
    bar    55/1=55


pt         stem,       bcell,        tcell
    foo      0       (23+22)/2        0
    bar      0       (12+13)/2        0
```

How can I achieve that?

I'm stuck with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("http://dpaste.com/1X74TNP.txt")
```

**Update**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("http://dpaste.com/1X74TNP.txt",header=None,index_col=[1,2]).iloc[:, 1:]
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.ix[:2].values)
df = df.ix[2:]
df.index.names = ['cell', 'organ']
df = df.reset_index('organ', drop=True)
result = df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1).mean().stack().replace(np.nan, 0).unstack().swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

gives:

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv(join(DESKTOP, 'bio.csv'), header=None, index_col=[1,2]).iloc[:, 1:]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.ix[:2].values)
df = df.ix[2:].astype(int)
df.index.names = ['cell', 'organ']
df = df.reset_index('organ', drop=True)

avg = df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1).mean()
result = avg.stack().replace(np.nan, 0).unstack()
result = result.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

        bm               fl               pt           
     bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell
cell                                                   
foo      0   15    79     0   11     0  22.5    0     0
bar      0   15    88     0   55     0  12.5    0     0
```

To access one of the attributes, use:

```
print(result.loc[:, 'bm'])

      bcell  stem  tcell
cell                    
foo       0    15     79
bar       0    15     88
```

Comment: No that won't do. I need to keep track of ever gene for, every organs.

Comment: Ok. So this sounds like you need a `MultiIndex` containing the gene and organs columns (the latter called 'celltype' in the first row). Next it looks like you need to organize your data by bm, fl and pt with different treatment for stem, bcell and tcell, respectively. What are the rules for either averaging, keeping as is, or setting to zero?

Comment: Thanks. The alternative is what I'm looking for. BTW, is there a way to slicethe result of 'alternative' by 'bm' or  'fl' or 'pt'.

Comment: Updated to fix the error - need to make sure data are `int` (or `float` if that is relevant for the full set), and illustrate the slicing.

Comment: Thanks so much. One last thing. Is there a way I can make `result` code line into multiple lines. Now the code is rather long.

Comment: would you mind checking this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34015185/how-to-normalize-multi-index-data-frame-with-its-sum-values-in-pandas