# How to normalize MultiIndex DataFrame with its sum values

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following CSV data:

```
id,gene,celltype,stem,stem,stem,bcell,bcell,tcell
id,gene,organs,bm,bm,fl,pt,pt,bm
134,foo,about_foo,20,10,11,23,22,79
222,bar,about_bar,17,13,55,12,13,88
```

And I can successfully summarize them this way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("http://dpaste.com/1X74TNP.txt",header=None,index_col=[1,2]).iloc[:, 1:]

df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(df.ix[:2].values)
df = df.ix[2:].astype(int)
df.index.names = ['cell', 'organ']
df = df.reset_index('organ', drop=True)

result = df.groupby(level=[0, 1], axis=1).mean()
result = result.stack().replace(np.nan, 0).unstack()
result = result.swaplevel(0,1, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```

Which looks like:

```
In [341]: result
Out[341]:
        bm               fl               pt
     bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell
cell
foo      0   15    79     0   11     0  22.5    0     0
bar      0   15    88     0   55     0  12.5    0     0
```

Now for every 'bm' 'fl' and 'pt'. I sum up the values result in this:

```
In [352]: result.sum(level=[0],axis=1)
Out[352]:
       bm  fl    pt
cell
foo    94  11  22.5
bar   103  55  12.5
```

What I want to do is to divide the section of `result` with it's corresponding `sum` yielding in this:

```
                bm                              fl               pt
            bcell stem            tcell         bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell
    cell
    foo      0   15/94 (0.159)    79/94 (0.83)     0   11/11     0  22.5/22.5    0     0
    bar      0   15/103           88/103           0   55/55     0  12.5/12.5    0     0
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could

```
sum = result.sum(level=0, axis=1)

print(result.div(sum, axis=1, level=0))
```

to get

```
        bm                        fl               pt           
     bcell      stem     tcell bcell stem tcell bcell stem tcell
cell                                                            
foo      0  0.159574  0.840426     0    1     0     1    0     0
bar      0  0.145631  0.854369     0    1     0     1    0     0
```